# Egg inplantation by alien in escapee

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to find old anthology story in which a man is escaping(?) across the desert on an alien planet and is apparently rescued by insectoid. While talking to an alien, the latter brushes his back, implanting egg/larva. He has been rescued as food for the aliens offspring, like wasp-spider.

Comment: Argh, I've read this one.

Comment: There's a famous story like this that doesn't involve someone escaping. I think it was in _Dangerous Visions_.

Comment: @user14111 Coming up dry so far. Have looked through Knight, Pohl, Kornbluth short stories to date.  Now browsing common library anthologies from the 70s.

Comment: Thanks all. The escaping bit might not be right, cannot exactly remember why the guy ended up sheltering? in a cave. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I know this one! It's by Kornbluth- "Freind To Man"! A criminal Terran crashes on a planet due to sabotage by his latest victim ( A young woman he has addicted to narcotic eyewash then forced into porn ), and he hallucinates all the people he has killed marching behind him, with her in the lead as he tries to cross a desert to reach help. he collapses and an alien creature rescues him, and as the OP says, the alien takes care of him prior to implanting her larvae in him. Key line - "Amy thirst, too"

Comment: Friend to Man it is, just pulled it down and reread it. Thanks very much to all

Comment: Nice job @Covertwalrus! I looked through Kornbluth books but I missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the OP's comment above, this story was "[Friend to Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56935)" by C. M. Kornbluth; originally published in *10 Story Fantasy*, Spring 1951, available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/10_Story_Fantasy_v01n01_1951-Spring_Tawrast-EXciter).

The insectoid is called a "screy," and the story ends in a manner consistent with your description:

> ... Smith tried to move and could not. The itching in his back was a
> torment.
>
> *The screy mother did not look at the prostrate host as she turned and crawled up from the incubator to the surface. Something like fond
> humor wrinkled the surface of her thoughts as she remembered the
> little ones and their impatience. Heigh-ho! She had given them the
> best she could, letting many a smaller host go by until this fine, big
> host came her way.*