# Short story? Human as insect host

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story rattling in my head involves the reader not realizing why "the child" is being warned by the parent to not disturb a container. The box (I remember it as a box, or crate?) holds a creature that can speak to the child. Later to be revealed as a flabby thing with watery eyes. Boils down to the child meeting their sibling's human host. Pretty sure it was a short story but it could easily have been an excerpt as I probably read it in high school in the 80s. We read many excerpts to save time.

Comment: Humans as hosts to talking insects sounds a bit like Butler's "Blood Child", but the details do not match. Still might be worth a look to see if this sounds familiar: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233115/classic-high-ick-factor-new-wave-story-about-humans-living-with-insectoid-alie/233116

Comment: Butler and maybe some conflation -- I think that happens to me sometimes also.

Comment: "A flabby thing with watery eyes" -.            *hey look everyone, I'm in a book!*

Comment: @DannyMcG Indeed you are - it's not just *anyone* who can be in a book! Congratulations.

Comment: There was a story by James Schmitz, that when I read it, made me think he'd beaten Butler to the punch. Unfortunately I've been unable to track it down.